# tastypie api not showing ForeignKey in json result

Tags: python, django, json, api

I recently started using tastypie to open up my api for a potential smartphone app.

**I'm using python-2.7 and Django-1.1.2**

Two things are confusing me

1: in the `EntryResource` class when calling the `ForeignKey`, they just call the resource along with the resource_name, when I do it in such a way I get the following traceback.

```
691. assert isinstance(to, basestring), "%s(%r) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string %r" % (self.__class__.__name__, to, RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT)

Exception Type: AssertionError at /api/v1/activity-stream-item-subject/
Exception Value: ForeignKey(<class 'api.resources.UserResource'>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

2: if I change `EntryResource` to `user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')`, then it runs fine without a traceback, however I cannot see the related information in the JSON response.

api/resources.py

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }

class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'pub_date': ['exact', 'lt', 'lte', 'gte', 'gt'],
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if I understand your first problem, but about the second one, you'll need to specify you want the full resource using:

```
user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user',full=True)
```

otherwise you'll get the resource URI instead of the contents. ([Ref](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-tastypie/en/latest/interacting.html?highlight=full#getting-a-collection-of-resources))

Also just for reference, keep in mind that the requirements state:

> Django 1.2+ (May work on Django 1.1)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to display all fields of User in json result, you have to set `full=True`.

```
user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,user,full=True)
```

Comment: true is not valid python